# Prevent manual instantiation of @ApplicationScoped CDI managed bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, java-ee-6

I have a Singleton class in my Java EE application.
I'm achieving this by annotating the class with `@ApplicationScoped` and letting CDI handle everything.

My question is whether I can prevent accidental manual instantiation of this class, since CDI requires that I have a non-private no-argument constructor?

The "classic" non-CDI solution would have a private constructor, a static `INSTANCE` field and a static factory method that returns this instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "classic" non-CDI solution you mention, and then annotate the factory method (or static final field) with `@Produces`.

Comment: I guess I have to read up on how `@Produces` works. Do I need the `@ApplicationScoped` anywhere with this solution? Does the CDI framework not get confused if the `@Produces` method always returns the same instance (since CDI should control creation and destruction of instances)?